# Web SQl Database Where is my database

Tags: html, web-sql

I found a neat tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm It sounds like it would be great to learn this but I can't find the location of the DB(s) I think it creates two but I'm, not sure. the code to create the db's doesn't give a path here it is:

```
    var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

I am using local storage so the db must be on my computer, but where? I found a question here that was similar but even though there was a reply, the asker still wasn't given a location for his db. I have used "Inspect Element" in Chrome but it doesn't give a location either. I know the database was created and the data written and read because the code indicated that.
Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Path of the database file should be something like this

C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\PROVIDER_NAME\BROWSER_NAME\User Data\Default\databases\IP_ADDRESS

Comment: You lost me at "PROVIDER NAME" What would that be?

Comment: @user1675122 If your browser is chrome, then provider name is 'google'